# Is there anyway to place data transfer limits on Amazon S3 so I don't get charged beyond a certain amount?

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm try to host videos on S3 and to put data transfer limits so I don't get charged for more than say 20GB, any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of

But you could try issuing **Query String Authentication** Urls to S3 resources with expiration dates set. And then use the **Server Access Logs** to track total downloads. It you miss by a GB or so it's not going to cost too much :-)